# Moment of inertia of a pipe

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

the wall of the pipe is very thin then my ideas was:

$$ I = \int^L R^2dm $$ where L is th elenght of the pipe then I will a bunch of hoops of dm:

$$dm = p2\pi RldR$$

replacing in the first eq and solving The integral I get:

$$I = \frac{ML^4}{2R^2}$$

however this is wrong. notice how the units of "m" cancel and this are not the units of moment of inertia where is my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there but use:

$$
dm = \rho 2\pi Rt dl
$$

for your differential mass, there $t$ is the pipe thickness, and $dl$ is the differential length.

Note that $R$ is a constant in this situation, and you are integrating in $l$ from $0$ to $L$. You do not have the lower bound of $0$ but I assume you understand that is what the lower bound needs to be.

It looks like the final answer is:

$$
\begin{align}
I = \rho 2 \pi R^{3} t L \\
I = M R^{2}
\end{align}
$$

because

$$
M = \rho 2 \pi R t L
$$

under the "thin walled pipe" assumption. The mass of the pipe in general is as below, and under the "thin wall assumption" it approximates as:

$$
\begin{align}
M &= \rho \pi (R_{o}^{2} - R_{i}^{2})L \\
M &= \rho \pi (R_{o} - R_{i})(R_{o} + R_{i})L \\
M &\approx \rho \pi t (2R)L \\
M &\approx \rho 2 \pi R t L
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I think the mass should be $$ p \pi R^2 t$$?

Comment: That would be if it was a solid disk. Isn't this a "thin walled pipe"? That term usually means that the radius is much bigger than the thickness. I'll include an update.

Comment: ohh I am sorry.

Comment: I updated it to include the mass.

Comment: how did you know you have to integrate with dl as the differential?

Comment: Technically you integrate in all three dimensions unless there is another option. This one really requires no integration at all. The cross section of the "thin walled pipe" is really just a hoop, whose 2nd moment is $mR^{2}$ (where that mass is really density per length). There is no variation along the length so you can just multiply by the length (this basically gives you all the mass).